# Django - Import Export - Save Field Names from Excel

Tags: django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class ExcelData(models.Model):
    var1                        = models.IntegerField() 
    var2                        = models.IntegerField() 
    var3                        = models.IntegerField()
```

---

And an excel sheet with 3 columns(col1, col2, col3).

I want to overwrite the field names of the model with the column names when I import an excel file.

Expected Result:

```
class ExcelData(models.Model):
    col1                        = models.IntegerField() 
    col2                        = models.IntegerField() 
    col3                        = models.IntegerField()
```

---

Actual Result:

```
 "Column 'id' not found in dataset. Available columns are ... "
```

---

This is how far I got:

```
@admin.register(ExcelData)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('id',)

class ExcelDataResource(resources.ModelResource):
    var1 = Field(attribute='var1', column_name='Custom 1')
    var2 = Field(attribute='var2', column_name='Custom 2')
    var3 = Field(attribute='var3', column_name='Custom 3')

    class Meta:
        model = ExcelData
        fields = ()
        import_id_fields = ('var1',)
        export_order = ()
```

---

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it it in column name, doc:https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-data

```
class ExcelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    var1 = Field(attribute='var1', column_name='Custom Name')
    var2 = Field(attribute='var2', column_name='Custom Name')
    var3 = Field(attribute='var3', column_name='Custom Name')


    class Meta:
        model = ExcelData
        fields = ( var1, var2, var3 )
        export_order = ( var1, var2, var3 )
```

Comment: Im trying to implement your solution, but I get "Column 'id' not found in dataset". It looks like it doesnt find and replace the fields when importing data

Comment: have you imported these two? from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field

Comment: sorry, please put all fields and export order in quotes

Comment: still same KeyError: 'id'

Comment: @admin.register(ExcelData)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('id',) remove it completely and see

Comment: How am I supposed to import data without the ImportExportModelAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

ExcelData needs to be updated to have a primary key:

```
class ExcelData(models.Model):
col1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
col2 = models.IntegerField() 
col3 = models.IntegerField()
```